# while disabling particular column of data grid view getting null reference error

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on windows form..
I have a data grid view say(3 column).i want to disable third column if i don't have data in first, two columns.
if i have data in first two columns then third column should be enable..

my data grid view like thise

[image]

if first two column have some data then i have to enter some id in third column.other wise i dont want to allow enter id in third column
so i wrote code in my data gridview cell_clik event like this:

```
String Cell1=dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
String Cell2=dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Cell1) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Cell2))
{
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
}
```

so when ever first two column blank ,if i try to give driver id,,getting error in this line

```
String Cell1=dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**..so which event i havnt write code? what s wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it the `DataGridViewCell.Value` is null then calling ToString() on it causes the exception

You could put a safety check with a [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
string Cell1 = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value == null ? string.Empty :
               dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

if you want to enable/disable row editing on the cell you need something like this

```
protected void dgv_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs  a)
{
    EnableDisableRowCell(dgv.Rows[a.RowIndex]);
}

protected void dgc_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs a)
{
    EnableDisableRowCell(dgv.Rows[a.RowIndex]);
}

void EnableDisableRowCell(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    string cell1=row.Cells[0].Value == null ? string.Empty : row.Cells[0].ToString();
    string cell2=row.Cells[1].Value == null ? string.Empty : row.Cells[1].ToString();
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell1) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell2))
        row.Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
    else
        row.Cells[2].ReadOnly = false;
}
```

Please, i have not tested it agains a live project. So just try it and if something doens't work use the debugger to see where are the errors

Comment: sir which data grid view event i have to write this code?

Comment: data grid view CellClick event only i have to write this code?

Comment: Well, it depends on how do you plan to interact with the grid. Probably a loop over the rows in the DataBindingComplete could be an alternative

Comment: or better in the [RowEnter event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so if i wrote this code in cellclick event that will work right?

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to achieve then you need also to use the [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event to reenable the third cell in case you user fills the missing values

Comment: No, you write a private method and call it from the two events, eventually passing, as a parameter, the DataGridViewRow involved

Comment: thanks for providing code..sir my fourth column is button,,if the same case is coming i want to disable that button..how i can do?

Comment: Please ask a new question.